# Append multiple excel file into one excel file by sheet in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have multiple excel files, and I just want to append them in single excel file based on the sheet (For example, Data of Sheet1 always append to sheet1 and so on for sheet2).

And i want to keep only one header of any one file, and while appending other files I want to remove the header column.

so far i have tried.

```
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)

path<- "C:/Users/KJD14/Documents/Test - "
dataFolders<- list.files(path,pattern = "*.xlsx")
dataFolders<- sort(dataFolders[starts_with(match = "Test - ", vars = dataFolders)])
files<- lapply(lapply(dataFolders, FUN = function(x){
  paste(path,x,sep = "/")
}), FUN = function(x){
  list.files(x, pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this you can read in all the sheets of one excel file

```
library(data.table)
library(readxl)
# Using the example excel file and only read in the first sheet three times
list.import <- lapply(rep(excel_sheets(readxl_example("datasets.xlsx"))[1],3), function(sheet){read_xlsx(readxl_example("datasets.xlsx"), sheet = sheet  )})

dt <- rbindlist(list.import)
```

Using an additional loop you can then also read in more than one excel file if you like.
I just found a new package, which at the moment is only on github, but probably could be installed. 
So please checkout:
https://github.com/ropensci/writexl
To install:

```
 install.packages("devtools")
 library(devtools)
 writexl::write_xlsx(dt, path = "temp.xlsx")
```

Please mind that I haven't checked the last lines of code if they work properly, so please test that on your own.

Comment: How to append multiple file in new single excel file.

Comment: Well, I prefer to export to csv and then go on from there, so `write.csv()` will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that returns a data frame with columns for file and sheet names for each file. In this example, not every file has the same sheets or columns; test2.xlsx has only one sheet and test3.xlsx sheet1 does not have col3.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

dir_path <- "~/test_dir/"         # target directory where the xlsx files are located. 
re_file <- "^test[0-9]\\.xlsx"    # regex pattern to match the file name format, in this case 'test1.xlsx', 'test2.xlsx' etc.

read_sheets <- function(dir_path, file){
  xlsx_file <- paste0(dir_path, file)
  xlsx_file %>%
    excel_sheets() %>%
    set_names() %>%
    map_df(read_excel, path = xlsx_file, .id = 'sheet_name') %>% 
    mutate(file_name = file) %>% 
    select(file_name, sheet_name, everything())
}

df <- list.files(dir_path, re_file) %>% 
  map_df(~ read_sheets(dir_path, .))

# A tibble: 15 x 5
   file_name  sheet_name  col1  col2  col3
   <chr>      <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 test1.xlsx Sheet1         1     2     4
 2 test1.xlsx Sheet1         3     2     3
 3 test1.xlsx Sheet1         2     4     4
 4 test1.xlsx Sheet2         3     3     1
 5 test1.xlsx Sheet2         2     2     2
 6 test1.xlsx Sheet2         4     3     4
 7 test2.xlsx Sheet1         1     3     5
 8 test2.xlsx Sheet1         4     4     3
 9 test2.xlsx Sheet1         1     2     2
10 test3.xlsx Sheet1         3     9    NA
11 test3.xlsx Sheet1         4     7    NA
12 test3.xlsx Sheet1         5     3    NA
13 test3.xlsx Sheet2         1     3     4
14 test3.xlsx Sheet2         2     5     9
15 test3.xlsx Sheet2         4     3     1
```

And then exporting to a single XLSX file:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(df, 'file_name.xslx', sheetName="Sheet1", row.names=TRUE)
```